# Зачем назначать результат выполнения запросов на вставку/удаления переменным?

Tags: php, mysql

Читаю унаследованный код. Вижу такие выражения:

```
$foo = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('some value')");
$bar = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'some value'");
```

Зачем назначать результат выполнения запросов на вставку/удаления переменным, которые после этого вообще не используются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем [документацию](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php):

> Для других типов SQL-запросов, INSERT,
> UPDATE, DELETE, DROP и других,
> mysql_query() возвращает TRUE в случае
> успеха и FALSE в случае ошибки.

Этот результат *может* использоваться для проверки успешного завершения запроса. То, что он не используется в коде ваших предшественников говорит об одной из двух ситуаций: либо проверка была, но её убрали, либо её хотели сделать, но не сделали. Ещё вариант: ваши предшественники скопипастили код, не читая документацию и не понимая смысла возвращаемого значения.